# Integration test on to verify text has all resx translations expected

Tags: c#, localization, integration-testing, resx

I am having a problem that some developers forgets to translate messages to all languages. We have a resx called "LabelInfoEnum.resx" and then there is overrides on this for norwegian (LabelInfoEnum.nb-no.resx), new norwegian (LabelInfoEnum.nn-no.resx) and swedish (LabelInfoEnum.sv-se.resx). Right now, we have no control over what additional languages new text is translated to.

On nightly tests, I am interested in creating an integration test that loops trough the LabelInfoEnum.resx and checks that all chosen languages has a translation for this text.

Note: We have some resx translations that are not complete. These should be ignored in the test.

I am having trouble creating this kind of test and I have never seen anyone else create something similar. Does anyone have any idea how this can be done?

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into the same issue. However I want to see all the errors, especially the incomplete and empty ones.

The code below will show you how I solved it. So I hope you will get the general idea and can adjust it to your needs. (If you still need it, since the question has been asked about 3 years ago.)

```
public static class ResxTester
{
    public static void TestResxForInconsistencies(Type type)
    {
        if (type == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(type));
        }

        var cultureResourceDictionaries = ResxTester.GetResxDictionaries(type);

        var emptyEntries = ResxTester.GetEmpty(cultureResourceDictionaries);

        var neutralLanguage = ResxTester.ExtractNeutralLanguage(cultureResourceDictionaries, type);

        var missingEntries = ResxTester.GetMissing(cultureResourceDictionaries, neutralLanguage);

        var dispensableEntries = ResxTester.GetDispensable(cultureResourceDictionaries, neutralLanguage);

        if (emptyEntries.Count > 0
            || missingEntries.Count > 0
            || dispensableEntries.Count > 0)
        {
            var message = new StringBuilder();

            message.AppendFormat("Found resx errors in \"{0}\":", type);
            message.AppendLine();
            message.AppendLine();

            ResxTester.Append(message, emptyEntries, " Empty Entries ", "Entries which do not have a value.");
            ResxTester.Append(message, missingEntries, " Missing Entries ", "Entries which are specified in the neutral language but are missing in the specified language.");
            ResxTester.Append(message, dispensableEntries, " Dispensable Entries ", "Entries which are not specified in the neutral language but are present in the specified language and should be removed.");

            throw new AssertException(message.ToString());
        }
    }

    private static void Append(StringBuilder message, Dictionary<string, List<string>> entries, string headline, string description)
    {
        if (entries.Count > 0)
        {
            message.AppendLine(headline);
            message.AppendLine(new string('=', headline.Length));
            message.Append("(");
            message.Append(description);
            message.AppendLine(")");

            foreach (var pair in entries)
            {
                var languageName = pair.Key;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(languageName))
                {
                    languageName = "<neutral language>";
                }

                var line = string.Format("  Language: {0}  ", languageName);
                message.AppendLine(line);
                message.AppendLine(new string('-', line.Length));
                foreach (var key in pair.Value)
                {
                    message.Append("\t");
                    message.AppendLine(key);
                }
            }
            message.AppendLine();
        }
    }

    private static Dictionary<string, object> ExtractNeutralLanguage(Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>> resxs, Type type)
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> neutralLanguage;
        if (!resxs.TryGetValue(string.Empty, out neutralLanguage))
        {
            throw new AssertException(string.Format("The neutral language is not specified in \"{0}\".", type));
        }
        resxs.Remove(string.Empty);
        return neutralLanguage;
    }

    private static CultureInfo[] GetAvailableResxCultureInfos(Assembly assembly)
    {
        var assemblyResxCultures = new HashSet<CultureInfo>();

        // must have invariant culture
        assemblyResxCultures.Add(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        string[] names = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();

        if (names != null && names.Length > 0)
        {
            var allCultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures);

            const string resourcesEnding = ".resources";

            for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
            {
                var name = names[i];

                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name)
                    || name.Length <= resourcesEnding.Length
                    || !name.EndsWith(resourcesEnding, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    continue;
                }

                name = name.Remove(name.Length - resourcesEnding.Length, resourcesEnding.Length);

                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
                {
                    continue;
                }

                var resourceManager = new ResourceManager(name, assembly);

                for (int j = 0; j < allCultures.Length; j++)
                {
                    var culture = allCultures[j];

                    try
                    {
                        // we got InvariantCulture
                        // don't use "==", it does not work
                        if (culture.Equals(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                        {
                            continue;
                        }

                        using (var resourceSet = resourceManager.GetResourceSet(culture, true, false))
                        {
                            if (resourceSet != null)
                            {
                                assemblyResxCultures.Add(culture);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (CultureNotFoundException)
                    {
                        // NOP
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return assemblyResxCultures.ToArray();
    }

    private static Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>> GetResxDictionaries(Type type)
    {
        var availableResxsCultureInfos = ResxTester.GetAvailableResxCultureInfos(type.Assembly);

        var resourceManager = new ResourceManager(type.FullName, type.Assembly);

        var resxDictionaries = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < availableResxsCultureInfos.Length; i++)
        {
            var cultureInfo = availableResxsCultureInfos[i];

            var resourceSet = resourceManager.GetResourceSet(cultureInfo, true, false);
            if (resourceSet == null)
            {
                throw new AssertException(string.Format("The language \"{0}\" is not specified in \"{1}\".", cultureInfo.Name, type));
            }

            var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();

            foreach (DictionaryEntry item in resourceSet)
            {
                var key = item.Key.ToString();
                var value = item.Value;

                dict.Add(key, value);
            }

            resxDictionaries.Add(cultureInfo.Name, dict);
        }

        return resxDictionaries;
    }

    private static Dictionary<string, List<string>> GetDispensable(Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>> resxDictionaries, Dictionary<string, object> neutralLanguage)
    {
        var dispensable = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

        foreach (var pair in resxDictionaries)
        {
            var resxs = pair.Value;

            var list = new List<string>();

            foreach (var key in resxs.Keys)
            {
                if (!neutralLanguage.ContainsKey(key))
                {
                    list.Add(key);
                }
            }

            if (list.Count > 0)
            {
                dispensable.Add(pair.Key, list);
            }
        }
        return dispensable;
    }

    private static Dictionary<string, List<string>> GetEmpty(Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>> resxDictionaries)
    {
        var empty = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

        foreach (var pair in resxDictionaries)
        {
            var resxs = pair.Value;

            var list = new List<string>();

            foreach (var entrie in resxs)
            {
                if (entrie.Value == null)
                {
                    list.Add(entrie.Key);
                    continue;
                }

                var stringValue = entrie.Value as string;
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringValue))
                {
                    list.Add(entrie.Key);
                }
            }

            if (list.Count > 0)
            {
                empty.Add(pair.Key, list);
            }
        }
        return empty;
    }

    private static Dictionary<string, List<string>> GetMissing(Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>> resxDictionaries, Dictionary<string, object> neutralLanguage)
    {
        var missing = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

        foreach (var pair in resxDictionaries)
        {
            var resxs = pair.Value;

            var list = new List<string>();

            foreach (var key in neutralLanguage.Keys)
            {
                if (!resxs.ContainsKey(key))
                {
                    list.Add(key);
                }
            }

            if (list.Count > 0)
            {
                missing.Add(pair.Key, list);
            }
        }
        return missing;
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked nearly perfectly for me, just had to pass in the correct resourcemanager and Bobs your uncle. Thanks.